# PHP convert simple array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this...

```
$array1
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [60] => 2
    [12] => 1
    [61] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [14] => 1
)
```

I am trying to loop through it and create a new array that looks like this...

```
$array2
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [count] => 2
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 60
            [count] => 2
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [count] => 1
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 61
            [count] => 1
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [count] => 1
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

What is the best approach?  Does anybody have an example they can point me at where something similar is being achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :)

```
$array2 = [];
foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
    $array2[] = (object)["id" => $key, "count" => $val];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the array as per:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
     $result[] = (object) array("id"=> $id, "count"=>$val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple loop to achieve the same.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
$new_array[] = (object) array("id"=> $id, "count"=>$val);
}
```